# ImportRange and Concatenate don't work

Tags: google-sheets

I like to do this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxx";=CONCATENAR(F26;"!I23"))
```

=CONCATENAR(F26;"!I23") is not working on the function.

I was tried some "" and ' ' '

but it doesn't work!. how can i do it?.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly are you asking for? what doesn't work? Your question is missing a lot of important information

Comment: this =CONCATENAR(F26;"!I23") , is not working on the import range

Comment: put all additional information into the question. you can simply edit it.

Comment: already! does .

Comment: Share your sheet

Comment: What error did you get? What uses your spreadsheet as decimal separator, a comma or a dot?

Answer (score 0):

I've fix your code as below ant it works in my environment.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxx/edit#gid=0",CONCATENATE(F26,"!I23"))
```

Comment: While this formula may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this formula answers the question improves its long-term value.